# Android Interactive Map With Custom Image

Tags: android, google-maps, mobile

I'm trying to make an android application that has an interactive map.

Then when the app is run and the user selects the map option it will enable location services to show the user where they are on the custom map- and notify them if they are outside of the bounds predetermined.

If they are within the predetermined bounds, I want to show their location on the map while the map is being viewed.

I'd also eventually like to add "areas" to the map that allows a button press or interaction.  Example: a "button press" that would allow text to display.

I'm just looking to see if there a either a solution built into to the google map API already, or if there is another open-source solution that has already been made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your so called "areas" you can use markers that are clickable and can add listener to them to perform custom click (open new Fragment/Activity or show some info image text etc.). This is good place to start :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker

For predetermined bounds you will need a projection that translate between screen location(coordinates) to geographic coordinates and vice versa.

Nice info for projection can be found here :

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection

Answer (score 0):

You checkout this example on github created by me [Link to github](https://github.com/Barai-Vivek/SimpleImageMapDemo)